# ASP.Net MVC Telerik Grid Master Detail Custom Icon

Tags: grid, telerik, icons

In Telerik MVC grid.
for Master Detail it give a Triangle icon(when we click it. it expands the grid and show the Details).

Can we have a custom icon instead of triangle icon.

I can change the image on the image folder but it will change through out the application.

I want it to change only for one page.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the CSS background-image like this:

```
<style>
.t-hierarchy-cell .t-minus
{
     backgorund-image: url("path_to_new_expand_icon");
} 

.t-hierarchy-cell .t-plus
{
     backgorund-image: url("path_to_new_collapse_icon");
}
</style>
```